# Как сделать запрос к БД исходя из выбора пользователя?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Получаю значения input radio, хочу собрать их в массив и с помощью него делать запрос с помощью PHP, база данных имеется, вот только если пользователь захочет изменить выбор, то в массив снова попадёт новое значение и не понятно какую выборку значений он в итоге выбрал. Как сделать так чтобы при изменении выбора пользователя, старое значение менялось автоматически на новое? Понимаю, что хочу сделать, но логика не посильна. Помогите.

```
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let arr = [];

if (document.querySelector('input[name = "genres"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "genres"]').forEach((elem) =>
    elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      let genres = event.target.value;
      arr.push(genres);
    })
  );
}
if (document.querySelector('input[name = "publishing"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "publishing"]').forEach((elem) =>
    elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      let publishing = event.target.value;
      arr.push(publishing);
    })
  );
}
if (document.querySelector('input[name = "pages"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "pages"]').forEach((elem) =>
    elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      let pages = event.target.value;
      arr.push(pages);
    })
  );
}
if (document.querySelector('input[name = "prices"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "prices"]').forEach((elem) =>
    elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      let prices = event.target.value;
      arr.push(prices);
    })
  );
}
if (document.querySelector('input[name = "authors"]')) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "authors"]').forEach((elem) =>
    elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
      let authors = event.target.value;
      arr.push(authors);
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто обернуть input-ы в form и слать данные этой формы ajax-ом в php (если не хочется перезагружать страницу). В файле php - принимать глобальный массив $_POST и из него получать актуальный выбор пользователя и по нему уже запрашивать данные из БД.

Comment: input'ы уже обёрнуты в form, а есть какой-то гайд, где можно посмотреть как это делается?

Comment: @gwinbleid     например: https://habr.com/ru/post/658139/ на стороне php нужно обрабатывать массив $_POST[...] в нем [...] - будет соответствовать атрибуту name инпута. Например: `<input type="radio" name="userSelect" value="val1" />` после отправки ajax-ом в php можно получить значение через `$_POST['userSelect']`. Если создавать несколько input с одинаковым name - нужно сделать так (как пример): `<input type="checkbox" name="userSelect[]" value="val1" />` тогда данные будут в `$_POST['userSelect'][0....n]`, т.е. будет многоуровневый массив, хранящий нумерацию и значения внутри name

Comment: О стороне php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

Ниже пример как можно реализовать добавление значения в массив с проверкой и исключением предыдущего результата.

Во первых, я предположил, что у вас для каждого созданного input определен уникальный id. Если нет, то надо создать или попробовать завязаться на какой либо другой уникальный атрибут(можно создать например data-* атрибут, допустим data-id)

Далее, у вас много дублирующего кода, я позволил себе его убрать.
Ниже пример.

```
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let arr = [];
// Функция для обработки резeльтата изменения в input
function adder(id, value) {
    const data = {id: id, value: value};
  if (!arr.length) arr.push(data); 
  arr = arr.filter((item) => item.id !== id); // Проверяем массив и удаляем данные по id
    arr.push(data); // Пушим новые значения
}

// Список name ваших input
const name = ["genres", "publishing", "pages", "prices", "authors" ];
// Циклом создаем обработчики
name.forEach((item) => {
    if (document.querySelector(`input[name = ${item}]`)) {
        document.querySelectorAll(`input[name = ${item}]`).forEach((elem) =>
            elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                adder(event.target.id, event.target.value);
            })
        );
    }
})

// В том месте, где вы передаете результаты из массива, для получения массива в старом формате.
const resultFilter = arr.map(item => item.value);
```

Comment: Да, всё верно, у input id у меня уникальные значения везде.

Comment: Пытаюсь опробовать ваш вариант, пытаюсь вывести массив, но почему-то ничего не выводится в textContent.

Comment: Какой массив вы пытаетесь вывести и что за textContent? В вашем вопросе и моем ответе такого нет...

Comment: Пытаюсь вывести массив resultFilter в <p> с классом "result"

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы делаете и как это относится к вопросу. В вашем примере вы собирали в массив значения из input, в моем ответе на выходе вы получите такой же массив, только с исключением дублей по id input... Вывод значений в <p> вообще к вопросу и проблеме не имеет никакого отношения. Возможно для отладки вашего приложения надо использовать не вывод значений в браузер, а обычный console.log()

Comment: Я просто хочу чтобы мне вывело результат, т.е мой массив в элемент, но этого не происходит. Как я понял в resultFilter после прохода по input должен получиться массив с вашей правкой(с исключением дублей), но вывода нет, в консоли без ошибок.

Comment: А так в целом ваш код понятен, просто не могу понять почему вывод массива не получается сделать.

Comment: Покажите, как вы это пытаетесь сделать

Comment: На следующей строчке после инициализации resultFilter вывожу значение этой переменной в переменную result через textContent.

Comment: console.log(resultFilter) и в консоли увидите, что лежит в массиве. Скорее всего вы не понимаете, как значения массива отобразить в браузере. Однако это не имеет отношения ни к вопросу, ни к ответу.